# Rails 3 nested resource route problem as form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, form-for

I have nested resources like this in my routes.rb - ([my rake:routes gist](https://gist.github.com/812840))

```
namespace(:admin) do 
  resources :restaurants do
    resources :menus
    resources :menu_items
  end
end
```

In the controller:

```
def new 
  @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
  @menu_item =  @restaurant.menu_items.build
end
```

Trying to create a new MenuItem (action #new), by the url: http://127.0.0.1:3001/admin/restaurants/1/menu_items/new I get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/menu_items#new

Showing /home/fps/workspace3/peded/app/views/admin/menu_items/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `admin_menu_items_path' for #<#<Class:0xb6582d78>:0xb6581f2c>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @menu_item do |f| %>
...
```

How do I make this form work? It was created out of a nifty:scaffold

**UPDATE**

I also tried this in the _form:

```
<%= form_for [:restaurant, @menu_item] do |f| %>
```

But ended with a similar error:

```
Showing /home/fps/workspace3/peded/app/views/admin/menu_items/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `restaurant_admin_menu_items_path' for #<#<Class:0xb68162b0>:0xb6813dd0>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for [:restaurant, @menu_item] do |f| %
```

Should I file a bug?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? 

A nested resource in the namespace admin should create the route admin_restaurant_admin_menu_items_path but create the route admin_restaurant_menu_items_path.

The :admin namespace are already set in the controller if you scaffold admin/menu

This must be a bug in rails ?

Comment: @bandola I asked /ryanb, and he pointed it to be most possibly a bug

Comment: @FabianoPS : any news about it ? Still got the same error message than you!

Comment: and still didn't found a clean solution on the web...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the problem is in the form. This worked for me:

```
<%= form_for(@menu_items, :url => restaurant_menu_items_path(@menu_items.restaurant)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: With this approach, I get the error:  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"menu_items"}

Answer (score 12):

`form_for([@restaurant, @menu_item])`

Comment: Due to the namedscope, it yields: `undefined method `admin_restaurant_admin_menu_items_path' for #<#<Class:0xb660ada4>:0xb6609ecc>` So I can only think it is a bug

Answer (score 8):

I'm having the same issue.  The only solution I have found is to pass a url to the `form_for`.

```
<% url = (action_name == "new" ? {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/menu_item"} : {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/menu_item"})%>

<%= form_for [@restaurant ,@menu_item], :url=>url do |f| %>
```

One additional note, you will not get `params[:menu_item] back`, instead you will see `params[:admin_menu_item]`.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: the only thing that helped me, even if it looks ugly

Comment: Great! It Saved my day

Answer (score 2):

You can look up your routes by running on the command line.

```
rake routes
```

It looks like you're calling your routes incorrectly.

Array notation would be:

```
form_for([:admin, @restaurant, @menu_item])
```

And the named route for create:

```
admin_restaurant_menu_items_path(@restaurant)
```

Comment: The first, yield: `undefined method `admin_admin_restaurant_admin_menu_items_path' for #<#<Class:0xb665b448>:0xb665a570>`

Comment: The second, yield: `undefined method `admin_menu_items_path' for #<#<Class:0xb6864780>:0xb6863790>`

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with nested resources and namespaces is a *Vietnam* (pita).

Here is my *nasty* solution:

```
= form_for @admin_menu_item, 
    :url => (@admin_menu_item.try(:new_record?) ? 
        admin_restaurant_menu_items_path(@admin_restaurant) : 
        admin_menu_item_path(@ admin_menu_item)) do |f|
    ...
```

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me correctly (for both new and edit resource) was:

```
form_for @menu_item, :url => url_for([:admin, @restaurant, @menu_item])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 5 (not that I imagine it matters) and this worked for me:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @restaurant, @menu_item] do |f|
```

The fact that it's `simple_form_for` rather than `form_for` probably doesn't matter either.

Funnily enough, I'm building an app with the same exact resource names.